# Chaplin/Backbone issue - "Add" event not fired when adding item to the collection

Tags: javascript, events, backbone.js, coffeescript, chaplinjs

I'm building a test application for myself, to learn more about coffeescript, Backbone, Brunch.io and Chaplin JS, but I'm stuck and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

This is my code in the todo-view.coffee:

```
View = require 'views/base/view'
TodoItemView = require 'views/todo/todo-item'
TodoItemModel =  require 'models/todo/todo-item-model'
TodoItemCollection = require 'models/todo/todo-collection'

# Site view is a top-level view which is bound to body.
module.exports = class TodoView extends View

  # Template data stuff
  container: 'todo-container'
  tagName: 'ul'
  className: 'todo-list'
  template: require './templates/todo'

  # Create a custom initialize method
  initialize: ->
    super

    # Create a new Backbone Collection with some dummy data to store
    @collection = new TodoItemCollection() 

    # Store the dummy data in the collection
    data = ["working", "studying", "gym", "sleep"]
    for todoItem in data 
      @collection.add( new TodoItemModel({ item: todoItem }) )

    # Render the view
    @render()

  # Listen to data events
  listen: 
    "add collection": "renderTodoList"

  # When the template is initialized we need to load
  # all the list items and append them to the container
  renderTodoList: ->

    # Loop over all the items
    for model in @collection.models
      todoItemView = new TodoItemView({ container: @$el, model: model })
```

The problem is: the event listener ( set in the listener object ) isn't triggered. So the @renderTodoList isn't called.

Calling the @renderTodoList directly from the @initialize function does work though. But I want the function to be triggered by the "add" event on the collection.

I've also tried to trigger the event manually by adding @collection.trigger "add" in the loop that creates the new data models. But this didn't work neither.

Any ideas what I'm overseeing or doing wrong?

Comment: To the TodoView. The collection is also bound to the TodoView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stefan,

I had similar issues when I tried to use the listen hash for events. I opted to setup the listener as such in the initialize method of the view.

@listenTo @Collection, 'add', @renderTodoList, @

-Hans

Comment: It's a long time ago I had this issue. With my current knowledge I can confirm this is the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

@stefan and @hans,
This solved your problem for no doubt, but you guys are not utilizing the power of chaplin collection view. It by default handles any modification to the collection. If you add/remove/change a new model it re-render itself, no need to force.
find the **Chaplin** [doc here](https://github.com/chaplinjs/chaplin/blob/master/docs/chaplin.collection_view.md)